# How to add vertex/edge labels to existing graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If I have already created a graph using `Graph`. Later, I want to add to the graph some vertex and/or edge labels, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

A random graph without any labeling:

```
g = RandomGraph[{11, 21}]
```

[image]

You can use `SetProperty` to add labeling P.S.

```
SetProperty[g, {EdgeLabels -> {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> "COOL"}, 
  VertexLabels -> {1 -> "STUFF"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: actually in version 8.0.0.0, it is not working `SetProperty[g, {EdgeLabels -> {3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> "COOL"}, 
  VertexLabels -> {1 -> "STUFF"}}]`. Looks like `SetProperty` can only set one property at a time.